# File not found. Apache + php-fpm

Tags: php, fastcgi, apache2.2

When I use default config without vhosts everything works fine. But when I add virtual hosts It not working..

Here is how vhost look like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName example   
    ServerAlias example.com                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   $
    ServerAdmin example@example.com
    DocumentRoot "/home/example/public_html"
    ErrorLog "/home/example/logs"
    CustomLog "/home/example/logs1.log" combined
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/example/cgi-bin/
    Alias /phpmyadmin /home/phpmyadmin

    <Directory "/home/example/public_html">
      AllowOverride All  
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
      DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm default.htm
    </Directory>

   <Directory "/home/phpmyadmin">
      AllowOverride All  
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
      DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm default.htm
      Options -Indexes
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

also I have this in `httpd.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>  
    FastCGIExternalServer /usr/sbin/php-fpm -host 127.0.0.1:9000
   AddHandler php-fastcgi .php  

    <LocationMatch "/status">
      SetHandler php-fastcgi-virt
      Action php-fastcgi-virt /usr/sbin/php-fpm.fcgi virtual
    </LocationMatch>

   Action php-fastcgi /usr/sbin/php-fpm.fcgi  
    ScriptAlias /usr/sbin/php-fpm.fcgi /usr/sbin/php-fpm  

    <Directory /usr/sbin>  
      Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks  
      SetHandler fastcgi-script  
      Order allow,deny  
      Allow from all  
   </Directory>  
  </IfModule>
```

When I visit page I get:

```
File not found.
```

Here is what i get in log file:

> [Tue Nov 17 19:50:00 2015] [error] [client 192.168.1.68] FastCGI:
>   server "/usr/sbin/php-fpm" stderr: Primary script unknown

Any solution for this?